# Raw copy with sector precision on windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, copy, dd, raw-disk

Is there some program for windows that is able to do what dd does in linux out of the box? I need to copy from a file to a physical disk in raw mode where I need to define offsets for input and output. So for dd, I'd need to use the seek and skip parameters.
I know there is (1) http://www.chrysocome.net/dd or I could try to
 (2) setup dd using cygwin but:

1. Does multiply the skip parameter with 512 (which I believe is
   wrong). I want to skip=4198399 sectors but it then tries to skip
   2149580288 sectors (bs=512). So with this bug, the program is
   useless for me.
2. I tried to use dd under cygwin as partially decribed
   here: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2000-08/msg00885.html.
   I did this

   ```
   mount -f //./physicaldrive0 /dev/enc
   mount -f of=/dev/enc if=/cygdrive/f/inputfile.dat skip=4198399 seek=4209089
   ```

and got

```
dd: opening '/dev/enc': Invalid argument"
```

Similarily

```
    mount -f //./Device/Harddisk0/DR0 /dev/enc
```

resulted in

```
     dd: opening '/dev/enc': No such file or directory"
```

So I am tired of trying with cygwin.

Are there other programs/options that could accomplish a dd kind of raw copy (maybe some disk editor)?

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention: The sector counts that need to be skipped do **not** define partition borders. So tools that rely on them are useless here....

Answer (score 3):

Use a LiveLinux CD of your choice (e.g. Knoppix). Boot from it and do the `dd` from there. Everything else is just a hack if you depend on `dd`.

Otherwise you can choose any imaging tool for Windows (e.g. Ghost, Acronis True Image).

Comment: Well, if I wanted to use linux, I would. But it should work with Windows. That is why I asked here... All imaging tools I know (including Ghost and Acronis) do not support offsets as far as I know.

Comment: @user462982 I hope you are not trying to image your running system. This neither works with Windows nor with Linux.

Comment: Nope, I just try to restore the **exact** partition setup of my 2nd HDD that existed before doing a backup and recover from it. Although I made a raw sector by sector image, the backup tool used for this task (Acronis) did some "optimizations" and moved the partition boundaries. This interferes with the drive encryption used, which I believe uses the sector count as some kind of salt.

Comment: Seems like the dd tool included in this package (http://gmgsystemsinc.com/fau/) is a good windows implemenation of dd. Will get back if I incur any problems.

Answer (score 0):

With [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), you can use `VBoxManage` [clonehd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdim), [converfromraw](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp59618720) and [storageattach](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storageattach), depending on what's suitable.

To automate, you can use simple shell provisioning in [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) or, better yet, write a template with [Packer](https://www.packer.io/). Installing these on Windows is a breeze with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).